# How are clock rate measured and what does it mean?

Tags: cpu, clockspeed, ghz

After some Wiki researches about clock rate, I find two question:

1. What does a cycle mean?
2. How does a cycle affect the processing speed?

Sorry for being a noob.... But really hope someone can answer my question, Thank you

Comment: Please point out the "Wiki" you have read.

Comment: There is (at least in theory) a "master oscillator" in the CPU which provides the basic timing signals for running everything.  The frequency of this "clock" is the clock frequency.  A "cycle" is one "tick" of the clock -- electrically the signal starts at some point (maybe zero, maybe -3, who knows) and jumps up/down to another voltage, maybe goes past the start point in the other direction, then returns to the start point to do it all again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does a cycle mean?

> Clock is a signal used to sync things inside
>   the computer. Take a look at Figure 2, where we show a typical clock
>   signal: it is a square wave changing from “0” to “1” at a fixed rate.
>   On this figure you can see three full clock cycles (“ticks”). The
>   beginning of each cycle is when the clock signal goes from “0” to “1”;
>   we marked this with an arrow. The clock signal is measured in a unit
>   called Hertz (Hz), which is the number of clock cycles per second. A
>   clock of 100 MHz means that in one second there is 100 million clock
>   cycles.
>
> [image]
>
> In the computer, all timings are measured in terms of clock cycles.

Source [Clock](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/2/)

---

#### How does a cycle affect the processing speed?

> To think that clock and performance is the same thing is the most
>   common misconception about processors.
>
> If you compare two completely identical CPUs, the one running at a
>   higher clock rate will be faster. In this case, with a higher clock
>   rate, the time between each clock cycle will be shorter, so things are
>   going to be performed in less time and the performance will be higher.
>   But when you do compare two different processors, this is not
>   necessarily true.
>
> If you get two processors with different architectures – for example,
>   two different manufacturers, like Intel and AMD – things inside the
>   CPU are completely different.
>
> As we mentioned, each instruction takes a certain number of clock
>   cycles to be executed. Let’s say that processor “A” takes seven clock
>   cycles to perform a given instruction, and that processor “B” takes
>   five clock cycles to perform this same instruction. If they are
>   running at the same clock rate, processor “B” will be faster, because
>   it can process this instruction is less time.
>
> For modern CPUs there is much more in the performance game, as CPUs
>   have different number of execution units, different cache sizes,
>   different ways of transferring data inside the CPU, different ways of
>   processing the instructions inside the execution units, different
>   clock rates with the outside world, etc.

Source [Clock](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/2/)

---

#### Further reading

- [How a CPU Works](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/how-a-cpu-works/)